Why $u_{xt}$ differs from $u_{tx}$ when transforming $x$ and $t$?
I am trying to solve a linear second order PDE with non-constant coefficients. To this end, I am taking a transformation in the independent variables $T: (x,t)\rightarrow(\xi,\eta)$, which I'll denote as $x=x(\xi,\eta)$ and $t=t(\xi,\eta)$ for brevity. My confusion arises in the $u_{xt}$ term, as I get two different answers when taking the $x$ or $t$ derivative first. The first derivatives are
\begin{align}
u_x=\frac{u_\xi}{x_\xi}+\frac{u_\eta}{x_\eta},\quad u_t=\frac{u_\xi}{t_\xi}+\frac{u_\eta}{t_\eta},
\end{align}
and computing the second derivatives I have that
\begin{align}
u_{xt}=\frac{u_{\xi\xi}}{x_\xi^2}+\frac{u_{\eta\eta}}{x_\eta^2}+\left(\frac{1}{x_\xi t_\eta}+\frac{1}{x_\eta t_\xi}\right)u_{\xi\eta}\color{red}{-\left(\frac{x_{\xi\xi}}{x_\xi^2t_\xi}+\frac{x_{\xi\eta}}{x_\xi^2t_\eta}\right)u_\xi-\left(\frac{x_{\eta\eta}}{x_\eta^2t_\eta}+\frac{x_{\xi\eta}}{x_\eta^2t_\xi}\right)u_\eta},
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
u_{tx}=\frac{u_{\xi\xi}}{x_\xi^2}+\frac{u_{\eta\eta}}{x_\eta^2}+\left(\frac{1}{x_\xi t_\eta}+\frac{1}{x_\eta t_\xi}\right)u_{\xi\eta}\color{red}{-\left(\frac{t_{\xi\xi}}{x_\xi t_\xi^2}+\frac{t_{\xi\eta}}{x_\eta t_\xi^2}\right)u_\xi-\left(\frac{t_{\eta\eta}}{x_\eta t_\eta^2}+\frac{t_{\xi\eta}}{x_\xi t_\eta^2}\right)u_\eta},
\end{align}
which obviously differ in the $u_\xi$ and $u_\eta$ terms. It is not immediately obvious to me that the differing coefficients are identical for any nice transformation $T$ as is my suspicion. Or are there known restrictions that someone can point me to/enlighten me on?

Your expressions for $u_x$ and $u_t$ are incorrect. The correct ones are
$$
u_x=u_{\xi}\xi_x+u_{\eta}\eta_x,\qquad u_t=u_{\xi}\xi_t+u_{\eta}\eta_t.
$$
(Notice that $\xi_x\neq\frac{1}{x_{\xi}}$, etc.)

Thankyou, that clears it up.

@Gonçalo When I am computing the second derivative, then, I must take derivatives such as $\partial_\eta \xi_x$, is this simply $\xi_{xx}x_\eta+\xi_{xt}t_\eta$? Which can each be determined given specific $x(\xi,\eta)$ and $t(\xi,\eta)$? Is there any procedure for when these equations are not invertible by algebraic means?

Scratch that, I've got it. Using the system of equations you get from taking derivatives of $t=t(\xi,\eta)$, $x=x(\xi,\eta)$, $\xi=\xi(x,t)$, and $\eta=\eta(x,t)$ we can solve for $\xi_x$ in terms of $t_\eta$, $t_\xi$, $x_\eta$, and $x_\xi$ which we can take a derivative w.r.t $\xi$.

There is a more direct route. Let's calculate, for example, $u_{xt}$:
\begin{align}
u_{xt}&=\partial_t u_x=\partial_t(u_{\xi}\xi_x+u_{\eta}\eta_x)=(\partial_tu_{\xi})\xi_{x}+u_{\xi}\xi_{xt}+(\partial_tu_{\eta})\eta_x+u_{\eta}\eta_{xt} \
&=(u_{\xi\xi}\xi_t+u_{\xi\eta}\eta_t)\xi_x+u_{\xi}\xi_{xt}+(u_{\eta\xi}\xi_t+u_{\eta\eta}\eta_t)\eta_x+u_{\eta}\eta_{xt}.
\end{align}
